# Is there a way to either query what would realloc do, or prevent it from copying all memory on Windows and Linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows, memory-management

I'm implementing a container similar to `std::vector` from C++. It has a buffer with associated capacity (memory which is reserved for this container) and size (actual size of the container).

When the user adds elements and size needs to exceed the capacity, I use `realloc` for the new capacity.

There is a `reserve` function for the container which sets the capacity in case the user knows it beforehand and doesn't want to risk allocating memory when filling the container with data.

Thus invariants might exist where the size is small (say zero) and the capacity is big (say 1MB). Then if the user calls `reserve(even_bigger_capacity)`, what am I supposed to do?

I can just call `realloc`, but if `realloc` does end up allocating a new memory block, it will copy 1MB of useless bytes into it.

I can have a constant: `WASTEFUL_COPY_BYTES` and check `capacity - size > WASTEFUL_COPY_BYTES`, and manually call `malloc` and `memcpy` and copy only what's needed, in case it's true, and only call `realloc` if the difference is small, but in this case I'm missing opportunities to use `realloc` where it **would** return the same address.

Basically I need something like `bool try_realloc(void *old_addr, size_t new_size)` which would return true if `realloc` would return the same address, but won't try to allocate a new block and copy stuff.

...or something like `void* part_realloc(void* old_addr, size_t new_size, size_t relevant_size)` which would only copy `relevant_size` bytes into the new block, if it ends up allocating one.

I'm sure there are platform-specific ways of implementing both of these functions, so my question is: is there a library with such functions which works on major platforms or, if not, how would I go about implementing something like this at least for Windows and Linux?

Comment: You can't protect yourself or your code from users of it doing bad things. Multiple `reserve` calls sounds like a problem for the users of your code. If you document `reserve` as possibly copying data, and the user disregard that warning, then there's nothing you can (or should) do IMO.

Comment: You could make your own malloc/realloc/whatever_special_version_of_realloc based on the source code of glibc and/or the MS source code. But this is probably not trivial.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude multiple reserve calls are not the only thing which can trigger this. Increasing the capacity when adding a new element to `old_capacity + sizeof(new_element)` is potentially too conservative. There is a growth strategy associated which increases the capacity with say x2 or x1.5 . Thus if you have 1mb cap and add 1 more byte, you will end up with 1 mb size and 2mb cap. Then if you decide to add 2 more mb to the buffer, all of the above applies

Comment: `in this case I'm missing opportunities to use realloc where it would return the same address.` My intuition says that such cases might be rarer than you think, but of course it depends on the implementation of the memory manager and on your usage pattern. Have you measured whether this optimization will be worthwhile? It's easy to check how often `realloc` actually returns the same address. And if it doesn't often do that, you might as well use `malloc`, `memcpy` and `free` so you can copy only what's needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, on Windows, [`_expand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/expand?view=vs-2019) is exactly what I need.

On Linux, things don't look as simple. I'll need to deep dive in glibc. Perhaps [`malloc_usable_size`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html) will be helpful.

edit: It's not (well not very much. It returns too few bytes more than the allocation size). It seems there is no way to implement this with glibc's public interface. The only way is to look through glibc's code, duplicate the data structures and use the chunk before the returned memory block, which is a Bad Idea™

I'll report further findings here unless someone provides a better answer in the meantime